# Exception for "effect of operation is undefined"

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

SICStus Prolog offers an abstract datatype ("mutable term") for efficient backtrackable destructive assignment.

The [user's manual subsection on mutable terms](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dlte_002dmut.html) states:

> **Please note:** the effect of unifying two mutables is undefined.

Let's say another Prolog system wants to implement mutable terms.

Unlike SICStus Prolog that other system wants to *define* the above effect using the `catch` / `throw` error mechanism.

What could be suitable error terms?
According to ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995:

> **7.12.2 Error classification** [...]
>
> e) There shall be a Permission Error when it is not permitted to perform a specific operation. It has the form `permission_error(Operation, PermissionType, Culprit)` where
>
> `Operation` ∈ { `access`, `create`, `input`, `modify`, `open`, `output`, `reposition` }
>
> and
>
> `PermissionType` ∈ { `binary_stream`, `flag`, `operator`, `past_end_of_stream`, `private_procedure`, `static_procedure`, `source_sink`, `stream`, `text_stream` }
>
> and `Culprit` is the argument or one of its components which caused the error.
>
> [...]
>
> j) There may be a System Error at any stage of execution. The conditions in which there shall be a system error, and the action taken by the processor after a system error are implementation dependent. It has the form `system_error`.

So `system_error` might be an option, but I think that a `permission_error` would be better.
How about `permission_error(modify,mutable_term,(=)/2)`?

Comment: In any case it always helps to go through all [error classes](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/error_k#error_classes). A representation_error might be an option too. At least for `current_prolog_flag(occurs_check,error)` `representation_error(term)` seems to be the most sensible. Alternatively, a permission error might make sense too.

Comment: @false. Thanks for your comment! I'm not quite sure about how this is like unification with `current_prolog_flag(occurs_check,error)` which actually attempts to unify and aborts before a cyclic term is produced (this may or may not happen). What I want for the unification of two mutable terms is to throw an error upfront (without further inspection of the involved terms).

Comment: @false. Here's another reason I'd rather favor `permission_error(modify,...,(=)/2)`. Suppose  the system does not support `copy_term` of mutable terms... then `permission_error(access,...,copy_term/2)` would parallel above error nicely...

Comment: Or existence error?

Comment: @false. Something like `existence_error(non_mutable_term,(=)/2)` and `existence_error(non_mutable_term,copy_term/2)` ?

Comment: Currently, `ObjectType` ∈ { `procedure`, `source_sink`, `stream` } So a value that fits into this somehow

Comment: @false. A somewhat strange, but quite literal translation of "the effect of unifying two mutables is undefined" could also be `evaluation_error(undefined)`.

Comment: @false. Alas, non-mutable terms don't fit any of the existing `ObjectType` values.

Comment: evaluation error is specific to evaluable functors.